# Finding Co-dimension of a subspace of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, quotient-spaces

I had learned about quotient spaces several times, but I always have a hard time with them in practice.

For a vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{R}$ with $\dim V=n$ and a subspace $U$ of dimension $k$, find $\operatorname{codim}(U)$.

I thought I proved it, but then realized I didn't refer to the field $\Bbb{R}$.

I argued that cosets $[u_1],...,[u_k]$ ($u_i$-s linearly independent vectors from $U$) are all $[0]$ since $[x]=[y]$ iff $x-y\in U$.

I then said $u_1,...,u_k$ could be extended to a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors $u_1,...,u_k, v_1,..., v_{n-k}$ and that for $[x]=\{x+U\}$ I can take $a_i$ with $x=\sum^{k}_{i=1}a_iu_i+\sum^{n-k}_{i=1}a_iv_i$ and that way $x-\sum^{n-k}_{i=1}a_iv_i\in U$ so $[x]=[\sum^{n-k}_{i=1}a_iv_i]=\sum^{n-k}_{i=1}a_i[v_i]$. Is that enough to show the dimension is $n-k$? How can the fact the $\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{R}$ be used? Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have to use it. The codimension will always be $n-k$, over any field. That being said, it looks like you only showed that $[v_1],...,v[{_n-k}]$ span $V/U$. You also need to show they are linearly independent.

Comment: You are correct, I am a little stuck with it. Cosets really confuse me, and I had known them for quite a while... I am going to give it a try

Comment: There's an awful mistake in my sums but I will change the letter of the parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must still check that the cosets $[v_1],\ldots,[v_{n-k}]$ are linearly independent. All this is true for any field $F$, including the field $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well I constructed $v_1,...,v_{n-k}$ stating that $u_1,...,u_k$ could be extended (in my H.W. paper I showed it inductively), but now I have to show that if $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i[v_i]=[0]$ then $b_i=0$?

Comment: @Meitar Yes exactly. And it is as simple as what you have already proved.